# Connector Style not being applied to jsPlumb connector when created dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jsplumb

**Update - 1**

Here is **[my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XbcZv/)**.

In this example. I have connected first two div on DOM load.

In this line of code

**JSPlumb**

```
jsPlumb.connect
            (
                {
                    source: 'A',
                    target: 'B',
                    anchors: ["RightMiddle", "LeftMiddle"],
                    paintStyle: { strokeStyle: "#ff9696", lineWidth: 8 },
                    connector: ["Flowchart", { curviness: 63}],
                    connectorStyle: [{
                        lineWidth: 3,
                        strokeStyle: "#5b9ada"
                    }],
                    hoverPaintStyle: { strokeStyle: "#2e2aF8", lineWidth: 8 }
                }
            );
```

I am passing the Connector Style.

**Query** - I want to show the source and target endpoints as Green and Ping. Right now it is showing blue.

**Original**

I recently took over a development left incomplete by some other developer. In the project we need to be able to draw connectors between 2 elements. For that the original developer used [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/jquery/demo.html). The library is working fine and producing results when I manually create a connector. But now what I want to do is create a connector dynamically. Reading jsPlumb's [documentation](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/usage.html) I tried to do it, but it is not producing the results that I want.

This is how it is when I create manually (notice the color and the arrow at the target element)
[image]

But if I create it automatically I don't get this color and arrow. This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p42Zr/) that I created for testing. What I am doing is calling `jsPlumb.connect();` and passing the parameters.

```
jsPlumb.connect({
    source: "page-1",
    target: "page-2",
    anchors: [
        [1.06, 0.5, 0, 1],
        [-0.06, 0.5, 0, 0]
    ],
    endpoint: ["Dot", {
        radius: 4
    }],
    endpointStyle: {
        fillStyle: "#5b9ada"
    },
    setDragAllowedWhenFull: true,
    paintStyle: {
        fillStyle: "#5b9ada",
        lineWidth: 5
    },
    connector: ["Straight"],
    connectorStyle: [{
        lineWidth: 3,
        strokeStyle: "#5b9ada"
    }],
    connectorOverlays: [
        ["Arrow", {
            width: 10,
            length: 10,
            foldback: 1,
            location: 1,
            id: "arrow"
        }]
    ]
});
```

Can anyone point out where is the mistake?

Regards

Jehanzeb Malik

Comment: @abcdefghi I am seeing Green and Pink connectors and no blue connectors on your fiddle.

Comment: Please check the connected endpoints of A and B which shows pink line. I want to know why it isa showing the blue circles. I want to show there pink color for A Endpoint And Green for B endPoint .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the jsPlumb documentation is imho a mess, I'm kinda surprised that this kind of question doesn't come up more often within stackoverflow. Here is what was amiss:

paintStyle.fillStyle doesn't seem to be around anymore... non of the demos use it, but the documentation still referes to it whenever paintStyle is defined within a connect-call. Strange, but strokeStyle does the job perfectly.

```
    paintStyle: {
        strokeStyle: "#5b9ada",
        lineWidth: 3
    },
```

What I would suggest beyond that (even though if you change that line, everything will work) is to call jsPlumb on jsPlumb.ready

```
    jsPlumb.bind("ready", function() { // your connection code here... });
```

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p42Zr/5/

EDIT:

The question was changed between loading the page and my answer, which i didn't notice. The answer up until here deals with the ORIGINAL.

The problem with the other fiddle is a bit different, what happens is that jsPlumb creates new Endpoints on top of the already defined ones. There are two ways of changing that. Retrieve the endpoints from `var myendpoint = jsPlumb.addEndpoint( ... )` and use this variable later on to connect them. The easier way in this case though is to add `endpoint: ["Blank"]` to the options. **(EDIT)** Setting the endpoint-Style to "Blank" means no endpoints will be drawn, which results in a connection and the two previously defined endpoints as wanted **(/EDIT)**. See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XbcZv/1/

**EDIT**
To answer a question which came up in the comments: How can I show the pointer-cursor on the connections?

Simply add:

```
._jsPlumb_connector {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**/EDIT**
to your css. For css changes on Endpoints edit the css class _jsPlumb_endpoint.

Comment: @e2bady That fixes my color issue. Any hint as to why I am not getting an arrow head at the specified location?

Comment: @Jehanzeb.Malik in my updated fiddle I can see an arrowhead... where else do you want one? maybe I can help somemore. http://jsfiddle.net/p42Zr/5/

Comment: @abcdefghi maybe I misunderstood your issue... didn't you just want to get rid of the blue endpoints in that fiddle? (Which is solved in http://jsfiddle.net/XbcZv/1/, where I added `endpoint: ["Blank"]` to the connection parameters)

Comment: @e2bady I want to show there pink color for **connected** A circle And Green for B circle .

Comment: if the further problem is that the connection is above the endpoints you can change that by adding a z-index... on connections you can add ConnectorZIndex : n on endpoints you will have to solve the issue with css.

Comment: @e2baby -   
Can you confirm that in JSFiddle in Div A and B there are blue circles ?

Comment: @abcdefghi can't go into chat, I'm behind a firewall which doesn't allow that. In your original fiddle the endpoints (your circles) were blue, in the updated version I posted, they are ping/green, like they are supposed to. Just to be saved I forked the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PmzTW/. I get off work in a couple of hours, if the issue still exists then, we can continue in a chat.

Comment: @abcdefghi I have put the meaning of `endpoint : ["Blank"]` and how to change the cursor on connection-hovers to my answer.

Comment: @e2bady I totally missed the fiddle. I guess that solved my issue. Thanks alot for your time and effort.

Comment: I am getting error after adding the code for `cursor pointer`. My **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XbcZv/2/)**.

Comment: Is it possible to set the pointer at the pink line only? right now it is doing on outer part as well.

Comment: That's happening because of the set z-indexes (well they aren't set, so it's in the order the elements are inserted) I set the indexes so the behaviour is as desired: http://jsfiddle.net/XbcZv/9/

Comment: It is still showing the pointer in the area above the pink line in IE9

Comment: Sorry, I can't really test that... microsoft makes that damn thing only for windows (I'm on a mac)... my suggestion is make it work for ie, but don't put to much effort into it, since a lot other stuff is not supported in ie... But I have one last thing you could try: Try setting `jsPlumb.setRenderMode(jsPlumb.VML);` which will perform better in ie...

Answer (score 1):

Set endpoint's style may solve the problem.

Endpoint's connectorStyle is a top priority. So if you have set endpoint's connectorStyle, then your connector's paintstyle will not work.

jsplumb's set paint style source code in connector.js:

```
        this.setPaintStyle(this.endpoints[0].connectorStyle || 
                       this.endpoints[1].connectorStyle || 
                       params.paintStyle || 
                       _jsPlumb.Defaults.PaintStyle || 
                       jsPlumb.Defaults.PaintStyle, true);
```

Comment: You're a genius! It took me 3 days to find your post!